# Propel Autoload Criteria

Tags: php, propel, autoload

I am trying to get the composer autoload also loading Propel Runtime Classes such as Criteria but I get an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Criteria' not found
```

until I use

```
use Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria;
```

My code is :

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'config/config.php';

$authors = AuthorQuery::create()
->filterByAuthorType(1,Criteria::NOT_EQUAL)
->distinct()
->find()
->toArray();
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is, that I upgraded from propel 1.x to propel 2.0 and I am using "Criteria" in several hundred classes. It is no option to put "use Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria;" in every php file where i am using "Criteria". So Criteria should be autoloaded, but it is not, even though I installed propel 2.0 via composer.

So the question is: How can I use "Criteria" without putting "use Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria;" into several hundred php files.